# How to send HTTP GET request with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I want to use ASIHTTP library to send the request like:

```
HTTP GET http://a.com/?user=abc&pass=123
```

I don't want to construct the string by myself because there are some UTF-8 encoding issue that I think ASI HTTP library has already resolved, I only can find the API to use:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:engine.userID forKey:@"from_id"];
```

But I can't use POST as the server doesn't support it.

Comment: -1 for ASI.  It's a sledgehammer to crack a nut, and it's not been supported for over a year. You're a smart guy, I'm sure you could figure this out with Apple's API in 10 mins, and think of the warm glow you'll get inside!

Comment: I am new to iOS development, I hope if you don't want to help you at least don't down vote. I am here seeking for help.

Comment: OR just switch to AFNetworking which is a nice alternative.

Comment: I also recommend RestKit if your project utilizes Core Data

Comment: @BinChen If you're new to IOS development, then take some time to read the documentation rather than reaching for the nearest 3rd party framework... you'll be glad you did in the long term.

Comment: @AshleyMills Be nice to the people around you, you will also benefit for long term.

Comment: @BinChen - Ashley's not trying to be mean, but it's hard to convey tone in short written statements. He's suggesting that relying on a larger third-party framework might not be the best way to go, and that it could be helpful to try to work with the built-in APIs first. There's been quite a bit of debate about the use of ASIHTTPRequest lately, which is where some of the sentiment here is coming from. Ashley's just trying to help by pointing out that using the underlying native networking methods might yield better results for you in the long term.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson - that's exactly the point I was (inelegantly) trying to make.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSString *profileURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bs.com"];

ASIFormDataRequest * request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profileURL]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"]; // or GET
request.delegate = self;
[request setPostValue:[self getJSONPostData] forKey:@"json"];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: why this is marked as an answer? setPostValue? Wasn't that supposed to be GET request? That aint working

Comment: the comment says "OR GET" next to POST he wanted the code for an ASI request

Comment: the question was about get, setin post values is just confusing. It was to me

Answer (score 1):

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myweb.com?Id=1&name=xyz"];
    __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer does not work.

Here's what you need to do to use GET with query using ASIHTTP.
In context of the original question, here's the working code.

```
- (void)_getDataFor:(NSURL *)url withHandler:(void(^)(ASIHTTPRequest *))handler
   {
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://a.com/?user=%@&pass=%@", @"user", @"pass"]];
      __weak ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
      [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
      [request setCompletedBlock:handler];
      [request startAsynchronous]; 
   }
```

You will have to create a "handler" block to take care of the response.
This code is ARC complaint.

Comment: Why are you declaring this as weak?

Comment: This is recommended by Apple ARC Transitioning doc (Use Lifetime Qualifiers to Avoid Strong Reference Cycles) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I know why weak is used, but what other object has a strong reference to the `request` object? Declaring it weak here means that as soon as you reach the `[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"]` line, then request will be nil. Unless I'm missing what has a strong reference to this variable.

Comment: I assumed the code will used as part of the instance method, edited my answer for completeness. As per ARC docs, "ARC works by adding code at compile time to ensure that objects live as long as necessary, but no longer. Conceptually, it follows the same memory management conventions as manual reference counting (described in Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide) by adding the appropriate memory management calls for you." So if the object is allocated and local to a method, it gets a release statement near the end of that method.

Comment: That is still wrong. The __weak specifier here means that the `request` object gets deallocated *IMMEDIATELY*, not at the end of the method. That's what strong (the default specifier) is for.

Comment: Please test this before rejecting it with your understanding of ARC.